# Im trying to chain promises on async fileRead but i get undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm experimenting with promises and async functions. Right now I have a script that should read a file `filenames.txt` for a list of filenames and parse it as an array so another `readFile` can read the contents of each file and log it to the console. Somehow the console is getting `undefined`.

This is my code:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

getFilenames = function(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile('filenames.txt', 'utf8', (err,data) => {
            if(err) return reject(err);
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}

getFilenames().then(fileNames =>  { 
    fileNames = fileNames.substr(0,fileNames.length-1).split(' ');
    Promise.all(fileNames.map(file => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fs.readFile(path.join('./',file), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
                if (err) return reject (err);
                resolve(data);
            });
        });
    }));
}).then(values => console.log(values)).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Just put a `return` before `Promise.all`

Answer (score 1):

You don't return anything from the first `then`. You need to return the result of the `Promise.all`. It will cause the second `then` to wait until the array of promises which you have created in the result of `map` will be resolved, all will be rejected with the first rejected value. Also the `return reject(err)` is a useless statement, you can't return anything from the `Promise`, so just use

`if (err) reject (err)`.

Code

```
getFilenames().then(fileNames =>  { 
    fileNames = fileNames.substr(0,fileNames.length-1).split(' ');
    return Promise.all(fileNames.map(file => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fs.readFile(path.join('./',file), 'utf8', (err, data) => {

                if (err) { 
                   reject (err);
                }

                resolve(data);
            });
        });
    }));
}).then(values => console.log(values)).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```